# WindowsIdentity Missing Groups - Particularly Administrators Group

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm using Impersonation to instantiate a WindowsIdentity on a Windows 7 machine that is connected to a domain.  I get back a lot of groups via Groups property.  Some domain, local, and builtin but I'm not getting the builtin Adminisrators group which the user is in.  I am very puzzled as to why this is happening.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

When I run, via command line, "whoami /groups" I can see all of my groups correctly. I'm just missing some when I use WindowsIdentity.Groups (particularly administrators group). If the whoami Windows command is figuring out my groups correctly how can I? I've also tried WinAPI NetUserGetGroups & NetUserGetLocalGroups which return even less groups so those seem like a bust. Is there any other way in .Net/C# or WinAPI that I can figure out all of the users' groups?

Answer (score 5):

This is the [User Account Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) in action. It will remove administrator privileges from accounts unless executed as an administrator.

> It aims to improve the security of Microsoft Windows by limiting application software to standard user privileges until an administrator authorizes an increase or elevation.