# WindowsIdentity groups not reflecting local admin status

Tags: c#, windows-10

According to Windows 10 accounts and the Local Users And Groups app, my user account is a member of the local Administrators group on the local computer but when I call the following:

```
List<string> allGroupNames = new List<string>();

WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

foreach (var i in user.Groups)
{
      allGroupNames.Add(i.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value);
}
```

the allGroupNames list does not show me as in any sort of Administrator group, local or otherwise.  I get a list of 50 odd other groups, including `BUILTIN\\users` and `NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users` but nothing reflecting the admin status the computers accounts suggest I have.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found the answer by now as its being long time from date of question. If not it is because of the User access control enabled by default in windows 10. Reference:
[Admin group doesn't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629691/windowsidentity-missing-groups-particularly-administrators-group)